# Error in BoringSSL CMakeLists.txt: Unknown processor:AMD64 - How to Resolve?

Tags: c++, grpc

The problem arises while configuring BoringSSL in a CMake project, specifically in the CMakeLists.txt file at line 89. The error message indicates an issue with an unknown processor (Unknown processor: AMD64). This error halts the CMake configuration process and prevents successful compilation. Seeking guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully configure BoringSSL within the project.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       CMake Error at out/build/x64-Debug/_deps/grpc-src/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeLists.txt:89 (message):
  Unknown processor:AMD64   BoringSSL   \out/build/x64-Debug/_deps/grpc-src/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/CMakeLists.txt 89
```

I attempted to configure my CMake project via VS22, but encountered an error stating "Unknown processor: AMD64" in the CMakeLists.txt file at line 89 after visual studio was fetching dependencies automatically. I expected the configuration to proceed without errors and for BoringSSL to be successfully integrated into the project. However, the error prevented further progress, hindering successful compilation.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an empty CMake project with just gRPC as a dependency? Using the `cmake` CLI? I think this is some kind of variable either added by your CMake project or VS.

Comment: which version of grpc are you using?